# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on shut down

Tags: kernel, shutdown, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ( it was a fresh install, I didn't upgrade it from an old release). Since then, whenever I shut it down, it always hangs on, sometimes as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

And the other times, it hangs on as it is shown here:

[image]

And then, I have to force it to shutdown by pressing the power button.

I googled this, and found this suggestion: 
Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` then update the grub.
I did as it said, but it didn't work.

Some additional information :

```
$ uname -a
Linux My-FRIEND 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A suspicious part I found when I run `dmesg`:

```
[   31.329263] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   31.414525] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   31.414609] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   31.484384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   37.467771] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   37.467779] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   37.467971] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   37.474593] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[   37.492246] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2194900161 Hz
[   37.492247] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.2.10_Ubuntu (interface 0x00290001)
[   37.501075] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   37.501461] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   37.506348] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   37.506631] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   37.511121] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   37.511416] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   37.513435] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
```

Is it related to the kernel or to my WiFi card?

Comment: I found something [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198357) that describes the problem of WiFi, but it is very complicated for me to understand.

Comment: The `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` only helps to display the error messages instead of the graphical splash screen. The first error is likely related to your WiFi but it does not seem to prevent your computer from the shutdown which is announced 3 secs later.

Comment: May be it is related to the kernel version, I had a similar problem before (with 16.04, but without `wlp2s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)`) and it was fixed with the release of a new kernel.

Comment: Do you know the version numbers of the kernel where it did not work and was fixed for 16.04?

Comment: That was in 2017, unfortunately I don't remember that..
I think I have to wait till a new kernel will be released, may be that will fix the problem.